# Group and count spark dataframe for approxSimilarityJoin

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sentence-similarity

If we have a dataframe output of model.approxSimilarityJoin of

```
val results =
  model
   .approxSimilarityJoin(vectorizedDf, vectorizedDf, threshold)
   .filter("distCol != 0")
   .filter("distCol < 0.2")
   .select(col("datasetA.title").alias("idA"), col("datasetB.title").alias("idB"), col("distCol"))
```

output of the above command

```
**idA|idB|distCol**  
A|B|0.125 
B|C|0.125 
A|D|0.125 
D|E|0.125  
F|G|0.125 
X|Y|0.19 
A|M|0.14 
A|N|0.14
```

we want the output to be grouped and count similar item i.e in the example above
we have

```
A, B, C, D, E  
F,G
X,Y
```

the final output required  should be  like:

```
A, 0.125, 5
F, 0.19, 1
A, 0.14, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something called approx DataFrame equality check in spark-testing-base

```
  /**
    * Compares if two [[DataFrame]]s are equal, checks that the schemas are the same.
    * When comparing inexact fields uses tol.
    *
    * @param tol max acceptable tolerance, should be less than 1.
    */
  def assertDataFrameApproximateEquals(
    expected: DataFrame, result: DataFrame, tol: Double) {

    assert(expected.schema, result.schema)

    try {
      expected.rdd.cache
      result.rdd.cache
      assert("Length not Equal", expected.rdd.count, result.rdd.count)

      val expectedIndexValue = zipWithIndex(expected.rdd)
      val resultIndexValue = zipWithIndex(result.rdd)

      val unequalRDD = expectedIndexValue.join(resultIndexValue).
        filter{case (idx, (r1, r2)) =>
          !DataFrameSuiteBase.approxEquals(r1, r2, tol)}

      assertEmpty(unequalRDD.take(maxUnequalRowsToShow))
    } finally {
      expected.rdd.unpersist()
      result.rdd.unpersist()
    }
  }
```

Design the algorithm based on your need.
https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/wiki/DataFrameSuiteBase

Answer (score 0):

we are trying to find something like Natural Join. in the above example,
A is related to B and B is related to C i.e A is related to C.
plus we have 
A is related to D and D is related to E i.e A is related to E

finally we should conclude that A is related to B, C, D and E with same similarity
i.e A had count to 5